# How to set total supply of native token in genesis file?

Tags: go-ethereum, golang

I understand you prefund wallet address with a native token in the `alloc` param, but where do you define the total supply at in the `genesis.json` file?

```
  "genesis": {
        "nonce": "0x0000000000000000",
        "timestamp": "0x0",
        "extraData": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f858f854943de75dbe6ecf6052f04332b510fb77e91ca2b9ed94e188bd4100f0d6ffa2be4877f61df3480d886ffe94698a814b3321a3ff9fc4ae215e1aa3f8faa1684694eec9b86866e53c7af6add74b892acd92e6d4f8fd80c0",
        "gasLimit": "0x500000",
        "difficulty": "0x1",
        "mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "alloc": {
            "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001001": {
                "code": "0x60<truncated>",
                "storage": {...},
                "balance": "0x22b1c8c1227a00000"
            },
            "0x3D...2b9ED": {
                "balance": "0x3635c9adc5dea00000"
            },
            "0x69...a6846": {
                "balance": "0x3635c9adc5dea00000"
            }
        },
        "number": "0x0",
        "gasUsed": "0x70000",
        "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    },
```

Bonus Question: how would you issue more tokens if you needed, like Ethereum issues more tokens?

Comment: Are you creating a PoW or a PoA chain? PoW chains do not have total supply, PoA is the total allocated to the genesis accounts.

Comment: creating PoS so I'm it's the same as PoA

Answer (score 1):

Ended up allocated 10m tokens between my initial validators evenly in the `alloc` param of the genesis.json file.

This is similar to PoA blockchains as @Ismael commented above.

You can also pre-allocated some of the total supply to pre-deployed smart contracts.